# Using `ResHelper` to get resource string uses thread culture not LocalizationContext

Tags: c#, kentico

Using Kentico CMS with a multi culture site, we have custom code to get a resource string,  when we use `ResHelper.GetString("someKey")` it does not use `LocalizationContext.CurrentCulture` version of the string, it is always defaulting to the US culture.

When I pass in the culture code to use as the second parameter using `Localization.CurrentCulture.CultureCode` it returns the correct string?

Using a quick watch and breakpoint at the code, I can see that `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` are both set to US whilst `LocalizationContext.CurrentCulture` is set to which ever version of the website we are viewing.

Why wouldn't Kentico set the Thread culture if resource strings rely on it?

We have used many resource strings throughout the site, some are using built in cms controls `<cms:LocalizedLabel ResourceString="someKey" />` - how do these controls work?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Kentico are you using?  Secondly, how are you switching cultures on the front side of your website?

Comment: We are using `v10.0.10` - we are just switching by using culture code in the URL at the minute, (eg http://oursite.com/en-gb|en-us|en-au etc...)

Eventually we will have different top level domains for each culture.

Comment: Then I'm guessing the issue is that the site doesn't fully know the culture because it hasn't been properly switched.  Have you tested in incognito browsers so you can verify something isn't cached?  It's not common for people to switch languages aside from just because they want to test the site.

Comment: I've found the same issue in Kentico 8 when I used ResHelper inside IHttpHandler, my default site culture was french (fr-fr), but ResHelper returned english (en-us) localization strings and it was really weird behaviour. I've solved it by setting up Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture manually.

Comment: Well something is setting LocalizationContext.CurrentCulture properly ... not sure when this gets set but would have thought they could set thread culture too

Comment: Could you please raise a support ticket via http://devnet.kentico.com/support ? This behavior seems incorrect to me. Thanks